# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'rv_frozen'

Tags: python, typeerror

Hi I am getting this error for this code and I am not sure how to fix it or what it wants from me regarding "rv_frozen" considering the < is between x and a number and x is clearly defined. Atleast I thought. relatively new to python, thanks!

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import uniform

for i in range(h):
    x = randint(0,100)
    if x >= 0 and x <= 15:
        D1 = randint(750000,800000)
        D2 = uniform(D1*0.1,D1*0.5)
        Profit = 65*min(D1,Q)+32*min(D2,max((Q-D1),0))-(Q*55)
        P.append(Profit)
    if x > 15 and x <= 40:
        D1 = randint(550000,750000)
        D2 = uniform(D1*0.1,D1*0.5)
        Profit = 65*min(D1,Q)+32*min(D2,max((Q-D1),0))-(Q*55)
        P.append(Profit)
    if x > 40 and x <= 75:
        D1 = randint(450000,550000)
        D2 = uniform(D1*0.1,D1*0.5)
        Profit = 65*min(D1,Q)+32*min(D2,max((Q-D1),0))-(Q*55)
        P.append(Profit)
    if x > 75 and x <= 100:
        D1 = randint(400000,450000)
        D2 = uniform(D1*0.1,D1*0.5)
        Profit = 65*min(D1,Q)+32*min(D2,max((Q-D1),0))-(Q*55)
        P.append(Profit)
```

Comment: It's helpful if you provide all of the code that reproduces your issue, like importing Scipy... If you read [the documentation for `scipy.stats.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.randint.html) you'll see it's not a function. You need to use `randint.rvs`.

Comment: @excaza What makes you think that's SciPy? https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: @cricket_007 ["Alternatively, the object may be called (as a function) to fix the shape and location parameters returning a “frozen” discrete RV object:"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.randint.html)

Comment: 'from random import randint'
    'import numpy as np'
    'from scipy import stats'
    'from scipy.stats import uniform'

Comment: @cricket_007 this is what is at the head of my code and the .rvs did not work for me

Comment: @DarrellThompson Please try `import random`, then use `random.randint()`